# How to manage the variable of the webpage template?

Tags: template-engine

Because of the complexity of the existing webpage templates, I am trying to develop my own template engine with both easier syntax and the function I need.

When implementing the function of "include an other template", I began to wondering how to manage the variables in the included template, and those in the template included deeper.

It seems that adding some prefix to manage the namespace is to solve the problem, but I think it makes the variable names too long.

So how can I manage them in a good and simpler way?

Comment: maintain visibility context

Comment: @OlegMikheev, I don't know much of the template engine, and what you said is not so clear to me, would you pls tell me more about it, 3x